# Perl string substitution in bash using field separator - Skip header line

Tags: regex, shell, perl, string-substitution

I am working on the anonymisation of several fields in a semicolon-separated text file.

For now I have the following command:

```
perl -aF'(;)' -ne "s/^.{$length}/$x_string/ for @F[2*$index]; print @F" file
```

Where `$index` corresponds to the index of the string I want to substitute relatively to the semicolon split, `$length` is the size of the string to substitute and `$x_string` is a simple string of X's.

For an `$index` equal to `1`, `$size` equal to `3` and `$x_string` equal to `XXX`, if `file` has the following content:

```
azerty;012;test;20181201;;wxc;
ytreza;345;demo;20160214;;nbv;
```

Then the `perl` command returns this:

```
azerty;XXX;test;20181201;;wxc;
ytreza;XXX;demo;20160214;;nbv;
```

My problem is that I want to skip and not to anonymise a potential header line. I know how to do it without the `for` statement - using `unless $. == 1` for example - but I don't know how to manage it when combined with the `-F` option.

Note that I will always have an array of size 1 because of my configuration file's structure pairing the `index` and `length` variables.

I am a total newbie with `perl` so I am asking you for some help with this issue!

Comment: The part after `-e` is just Perl code, so you can use `"if( $. > 1 ) { ... s/// }; print @F"` . But if you're always printing, use `-p` instead of `-n` ?

Comment: But unless you're on Windows, mixing double quotes and dollar signs is likely bad, as your shell will then interpolate what it thinks are shell variables while you think of them as Perl variables?! Otherwise, use `\$.` instead of `$.` so that `$.` gets passed through to Perl. Also consider converting your oneliner to a script instead.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Actually I am doing in-place edition so the following command works well: `perl -aF'(;)' -ne 'if( $. > 1 ) { s/^.{3}/XXX/ for @F[2] }; print @F' -i file`. But I don't get how to use the `-p` option instead of the `print @F` command. Do you have any tip? Thanks!

Comment: Oh - no, `-p` wouldn't help much then. You'd need `$_ = @F` so that `-p` works, so your approach is good enough using `-n`.

Answer (score 1):

Just condition the change (regex) itself on `$.` and otherwise do the same (print)

```
perl -aF'(;)' -ne'$F[2*$index] =~ s/^.{$length}/$x_string/ unless $.==1; print @F' file
```

There is no need for the `for` loop since you specify precisely one `@F` element to change. (Also, with `-w` you'd be seeing a warning for writing a scalar as array/list, using `@` sigil.)

---

One other way is to change `$_` directly using regex and use `-p`. Since `-p` always prints `$_`, even if lines aren't processed, now you can simply skip the first line

```
perl -pe'next if $.==1; s/(?:.*?;){$index}\K.{$length}/$x_string/' file
```

The regex matches `$index` sequences ending with `;`, grouped without capture due to `?:`, and then [`\K` assertion](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) drops all that so the substitution happens only for what is matched next. So this regex changes the `$length` characters following the `$index`-th semicolon.

Comment: @JulienCamus Edited

Answer (score 0):

`-n` wraps

```
LINE: while (<>) {
    ... # your program goes here
}
```

around your script so you can add `next LINE if $. == 1;` to your one liner to skip the header.

```
perl -aF'(;)' -ne "if (1 .. 1) { print; next LINE } s/^.{$length}/$x_string/ for @F[2*$index]; print @F" file
```

This uses the flip flop operator `..` to count the first line and the block in the if statement then prints it.

Comment: This solution does not print the header line at all. What I want is not to substitute this line but print it anyway. Do you have another idea? Thanks!